# Null Pointer Exception- show Orders placed by User in a ListView from Server

Tags: android, android-listview

I am trying to fetch orders placed by user in ListView from Server, but i am always getting **NULL POINTER EXCEPTION** here:- *tName.setText(strName);*

**Requirement:**

*I want to fetch all these orders in a ListView*

**Logcat Status:**

```
05-23 09:41:05.684: D/CartAdapter(784): MemberID:: 1
05-23 09:41:05.953: D/CartAdapter(784): strMemberID 37
05-23 09:41:05.953: D/CartAdapter(784): strName Samosa(2)(Rs.3.75),Vegetable Pakora(3)(Rs.3.75),Veggie(1)(Rs.5.25),Daal Soup(4)(Rs.3.25),
05-23 09:41:05.953: D/AndroidRuntime(784): Shutting down VM
05-23 09:41:06.034: E/AndroidRuntime(784): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-23 09:41:06.034: E/AndroidRuntime(784):  at OrdersActivity.showInfo(OrdersActivity.java:91)
```

In PHP i am using below query to fetch record(s):

```
 $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM order_details WHERE 1 AND MemberID = '".$strMemberID."' ";
```

Comment: comment out `tName.setText(strName);` and the other `setText()` 
and see what you getting at the log for `Log.d(CartAdapter.LOG_TAG, "tName " + tName);` and `Log.d(CartAdapter.LOG_TAG, "tId " + tId);`

Comment: Can you tell us which one is the n° 91 line in OrdersActivity?

Comment: @HossamOukli like you can see above: tName.setText(strName);

Comment: @AtifFarrukh see my above code, i already Logged and you can see result as well

Comment: If I am not wrong these logs are from `Log.d(CartAdapter.LOG_TAG, "MemberID:: " + MemberID);` and `Log.d(CartAdapter.LOG_TAG, "strName " + strName);`; then that means null error is given at `setText()`. Please make sure that `txtTotalAmount` and `txtItemDetails` are in your layout `activity_orders`.

Answer (score 1):

This is completely wrong implementation.

You are trying to access TextView out of context. In fact there never exists any tname in your activity_orders.xml.

From the description it looks like you are trying to implement custom list view using base adapter. You will have to assign the values in getView method of CustomAdapter after inflating the view.

Please read some implementation of Custom ListView.

References: [Link 1](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/)
[Link 2](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=6816874)

Answer (score 0):

While I can't see the xml layout I can attempt to help.

First I would, in debug perspective, go to the "breakpoints" view and click the J! Icon (exception breakpoint). Type in `NullPointerException` and hit enter.

Now your code will break execution at the point of the exception and you should be able to see what property is in fact null.

Also, check if there is an inner exception by expanding the exception. There may have been another exception that occured before but caused a `nullpointerexception`

Comment: like i have written above: I am trying to fetch orders placed by user in ListView from Server, but i am always getting NULL POINTER EXCEPTION here:- tName.setText(strName);

Answer (score 0):

check whether R.id.txtItemDetails is inside the layout R.layout.activity_orders because if it cant get the reference to tName and you try to use setText it will throw a NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION as tName will not be referencing to anything

Comment: i have posted xml scripts also please check above,

Comment: setContentView(R.layout.activity_orders); so  tName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtItemDetails); will look for txtItemDetails inside activity_orders since it cant will it will not return the reference hence tName will have a Null pointer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. In your `showInfo();` Add the `strMemberID` and `strName` in the `itemsList`
2. cut and paste `adapter = new OrdersAdapter(this, itemsList);` and `list.setAdapter(adapter);` after point 1
3. In your `OrdersAdapter.java` `getView()` add `TextView tId = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtTotalAmount);` after inflating view set the text from the `itemList`

Comment: bhai jaan i agree with you, i hope you will not mind, actually i am facing this problem for last 2 days, i am getting confuse, please place code as your answer here, as you think it should be and look like, use above code

Comment: buddy can you show me code as i need to implement in my code it would be better to understand, because you have shown me right direction